# Split a three dimensional array into 2 in MatLab

Tags: matlab

So in matlab I have a 3d array A with dimensions nxmxk double. I have a split point L where I want 2 split the array into 2 smaller 3d arrays with first=A(:,:,1-L) and second=A(:,:L+1-end).
So to help visualise, I basically have a single dimensional array of matrices, and I want to split it into two distinct arrays of matrices. I've tried using A(:,:,[1,L]) and A(:,:,[L+1,end]) however in the case that A is size 2 in the 3rd dimension this does not work. Any help?

Comment: Provide a sample of `A`. Explain what you mean by *"doesn't work*". n×m×k is  a 3d matrix, (not a  *single dimensional array of matrices* if m and k do not equal 1). Please see [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

use this code as a guide to solve your problem

```
A = rand(10,10,10);
L = 5;
first = A(:,:,1:L);
second = A(:,:,L+1:end);
```